# Calling a method from a helper file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

In my application_helper.rb, I have the following:

```
def some_method
  do something
end
```

In my application_controller.rb, I have the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  require 'json'
  require 'csv'
end
```

In my data_uploads_controller.rb, I have the following:

```
class DataUploadsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_data_upload, only: [:show, :destroy]
  include DataUploadsHelper
  before_filter some_method
```

However, I am getting the error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `some_method' for DataUploadsController:Class\
```

Wouldn't including the ApplicationHelper in the application_controller mean that the methods declared in the ApplicationHelper are within scope for all controllers?

Comment: You have to pass the method as a symbol: `before_filter :some_method`

Comment: Yes, of course. I did not notice it. If you change this to an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the method as a symbol:

```
before_filter :some_method
```